# how to format one element of multi array (of php) in jquery part code

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, variables

When i Login this part of the code is executed:

```
 $_SESSION['user'] = array('user_id' => $user[0]['user_id'], 'IP' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

now on the upfollowing php page this code has to read the user_id

```
 $.tablesorter.setFilters( table, ['', '<?=$_SESSION["favcolor"];?>'  ], true);
```

where 'favcolor' is, needs the 'user_id' be...

but how do i format that?

i thought it was like so: 
(i got that idea from this site, i thougth it was a Multi array  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp )

```
 '<?=$_SESSION[0][1];?>'
```

but that does not work..

so how should it be formated then?

pls help

almost there, only the word 'ARRAY' is now in the column

```
$.tablesorter.setFilters( table, ['', '<?=$_SESSION["user"];?>'  ], true);
```

Comment: extra info... print_r($_SESSION);   gives back       Array ( [favcolor] => zelf [user] => Array ( [user_id] => 12 [IP] => 55.555.555.55 ) )

Comment: almost... now the word ARRAY is in the column...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SESSION['user']['user_id']` to access `user_id` from the `$_SESSION` array.

In this :

```
$.tablesorter.setFilters( table, ['', '<?=$_SESSION["user"];?>'  ], true);
```

You are getting `ARRAY` because `$_SESSION["user"]` is really an array containing `user_id` and `IP`. You need to specify the index `user_id` for retrieving the value of `user_id` from that.

Comment: $.tablesorter.setFilters( table, ['', '<?=$_SESSION["user"]["user_id"];?>'  ], true);